# SELECT with a chance of showing

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this database:

```
John 4.2
Robert 6
Maria 3.2
```

What I would want is lets say I refresh a website. And in every refresh I will get a random name from that database based on the chance of showing-> that would mean that Robert would appear more times than the other people(because of his chance)

Any way to do this? I just can't think of anything.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 2):

I've create your `table` with columns `name` and `weight`.
The following request return on name, depending on the weight:

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY RAND()*weight DESC LIMIT 1;
```